# IncompatibleClassChangeError in Java 8 (Lambda expression)

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

I am trying to learn lambda expression so following http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lambda-1984522.html.
Downloaded following IDE and JDK

> JDK 8 Eclipse IDE with JDK 8 support

But When after compiled following code, I had an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:444)
    at com.ahmetk.java8.Hello.main(Hello.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metaFactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodHandle,MethodType)CallSite/invokeStatic
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:800)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:917)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1101)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1363)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:442)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metaFactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:889)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:914)
```

Simple code that I am trying to execute.

```
public class Hello {
    interface HelloService {
        String hello(String firstname, String lastname);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloService helloService = (String firstname, String lastname) -> {
            String hello = "Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname;
            return hello;
        };
        System.out.println(helloService.hello(args[0], args[1]));

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try this on NetBeans? Also, try to clean and build the project.

Comment: No I have not tried it on Netbeans

Comment: Try it there. Eclipse is not yet completely stable for use with Java 8. Also try just to compile from command line, or terminal whatever you have.

Comment: you are right, eclipse has problem in supporting java8. I have successfully compiled and runned on command prompt.

Comment: FYI, Java 8 support on Netbeans is already really good, including very useful hints to auto-create lambda code.

Comment: IntelliJ 12 also supports JDK 8 very well. You can try it on the Community Edition for free.

Comment: you are right IntelliJ Idea is the best IDE that I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eclipse has problem in supporting java8. I have successfully compiled and runned on command prompt

> D:\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_32Bit\bin\javac com/ahmetk/java8/Hello.java
>
> D:\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_32Bit\bin\java -cp . com.ahmetk.java8.Hello 12 12
> Hello 12 12

Comment: this is most likely a problem with the eclipse compiler, and the java8 runtime. just use the jdk8 compiler and runtime and you will be fine.

Comment: As you may see that I am pointing jdk8 at eclipse, it indicates that there is something wrong cases not to run application properly

Comment: eclipse has a separate compiler it uses, it does not use the compiler included in the jdk.

Comment: I don't think so, since I can change the JDK version,let say using 1.7,1.6 where lambda expression is not known.

Comment: that is a language level setting. eclipse just passes that setting into its own internal compiler. if you want eclipse to use the external compiler, use ant ant script, or a custom build step.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your pom.xml, if you're using Maven

```
  <build>  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```